# Flutter/Dart - File.writeAsBytes executes with no error but can't find the file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a base64 encoded string of a PDF file. I'm trying to save it as a file in the android device. My code runs with no error, but i can't find the file.

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(encodedStr);

String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectories(
                type: StorageDirectory.downloads))!
            .first
            .path;

File file = File("$dir/" +
            DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
            ".pdf");

await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Also, I tried to include code to ask for permission before trying to save the file, but it didn't change anything.

```
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
}

if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
    try {
        await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

And, as another attempt, I included these permission on my AndroidManifest file. Also, no changes.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    

//dir = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/files/Download
//dir + file = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/files/Download/1655924904315.pdf
//file path after written = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx/files/Download/1655924904315.pdf
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or something that I can change in order for it to work ?

The above code is using path_provider and permission_handler packages and was tested in an emulator and in a physical device.

Thanks.

Comment: Print the dir path and file path after its written and check if you are checking in the same directory

Comment: @KaushikChandru, I updated the question with the info you mentioned. Considering the path, the file should be in the downloads folder. But it's not there nor elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that the files are being correctly generated, but they are being saved in the application's directory. A download folder has being created and the files are being saved there. I didn't find the files searching via android, but when I connected my physical device to a PC I was able the find them.

It seems that this has something to do with this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783 . Path_provider started to return application document directory after 1.1.0 instead of the general downloads folder.

I'll check how to access the path I want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing io and use file of io and use this package https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

final pdf = pw.Document();

    
    final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = "${dir.path}/pdfname.pdf";
    final file = await io.File(path).writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
```